# On the sublevel set inclusion of a function $f$ majorized by another function $g$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

Let $f: U \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function defined on a bounded open $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ with the property:
\begin{align*}
  f(x) \to +\infty \text{ as } x \to \partial U.
\end{align*}
In $x \to \partial U$, I mean for every sequence $\{x_k\} \subset U$ such that $x_k \to y$ where $y \in \partial U$. 
It is not hard to show this property is equivalent to: for every $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, the sublevel set $S_{\alpha} = \{x \in U: f(x) \le \alpha\}$ is compact.

Now pick an arbitrary point $\zeta \in U$. Denote the sublevel set $S_{\zeta} = \{x \in U: f(x) \le f(\zeta)\}$ and assume it has nonempty interior. Now let $c = \sup\{\|\nabla^2 f(x)\|_2: x \in S_{\zeta}\}$. That is, the norm of Hessian of $f$ over $S_{\zeta}$ is bounded by $c$. We build a function $g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ by
\begin{align*}
  y \mapsto f(\zeta) + \langle \nabla f(\zeta), y-\zeta) + \frac{c}{2} \|y-\zeta\|_2^2.
\end{align*}
Then $g(\zeta) = f(\zeta)$ and $g$ majorizes $f$ on $S_{\zeta}$, i.e., $g(z) \ge f(z)$ for all $z \in S_{\zeta}$.

My question is whether the point $\tilde{\zeta} := \text{argmin} \{g(x): x \in \mathbb R^n\} = \zeta -\frac{1}{c} \nabla f(\zeta)$ is contained in $S_{\zeta}$.

This is not obvious to me since the inclusion of sublevel set is $S_{\zeta} \subset \{y: g(y) \le g(\zeta) = f(\zeta)\}$, not the other way. It is not necessarily $\tilde{\zeta}$ would lie in $S_{\zeta}$. My thought on this is: $g$ is continuous on $S_{\zeta}$ with $g(\partial S_{\zeta}) = f(\zeta)$ and nonconstant, the stationary point must lie in the inerior of $S_{\zeta}$. Is this a correct thinking?

---

After reading copper.hat's answer, I have this thought (possible wrong and will appreciate if someone points out): Denote the univariate function $\psi(t) = f(\zeta+ t(\tilde{\zeta}-\zeta)) = f(\zeta - \frac{1}{c} \nabla f(\zeta))$. Let $T$ be a connected component in $S_{\zeta}$ containing $\zeta$. The ray $\zeta + t(\tilde{\zeta} - \zeta) = \zeta - t\frac{1}{c} \nabla f(\zeta)$ will meet $T$ at another point (possibly more than one, we pick the first one of intersection), say $\xi$ with $\xi = \zeta + s(\tilde{\zeta} - \zeta)$. On the line segment $[\zeta, \xi]$, $\psi$ should dominate $f$. But we have $\psi(0) = f(\zeta)$ and $\psi(s) \ge f(\xi) = f(\zeta)$ since $\xi, \zeta \in \partial S_{\zeta}$. Should this imply the stationary point must lie in $S_{\zeta}$ even without the assumption on $U$ by Rolle's theorem and intermediate value theorem?

Comment: I didn't catch this before I added my answer. You need more conditions (or fewer, maybe) on $U$. For example, if $U$ is not connected then it is straightforward to create an example where $g$ does not dominate $f$ on $S_\zeta$. Perhaps $U$ should be convex? There is nothing, for example, that allows us to conclude that $\tilde \zeta \in U$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks for answering my question. You are right and we need the assumption of convexity of $U$ to guarantee $g$ dominating $f$.

Comment: @copper.hat: I was actually in mind to find a suitable step size of gradient descent for such function $f$ with same assumptions in the question ($U$ is not necessarily convex). Could you comment on whether there is some definitive choice of step size besides line search? Thanks.

Comment: Hard to comment without more context, I doubt that a uniformly applicable rule exists. The existence of $c$ may allow a step size choice that avoids a search, but I would need to think about it...

Comment: Thanks. I actually asked the question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924646/gradient-descent-step-size-for-a-c-infty-coercive-function.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thinking it more, is it enough to assume $U$ to be connected but without convex? You mentioned the assumption on $U$ (convexity or connectedness) is to guarantee $\tilde{\zeta} \in U$ but I could not see why this follows. Thanks.

Comment: @copper.hat: I have another thought on the problem. Too long for a comment and I put in the question. Will appreciate if you could confirm or point out where it was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The presence of $U$ is a rather difficult one to deal with. In my answer, I needed to make 3 assumptions on $U$ to come to some conclusion, one of which was that $\zeta \in U$. Without these assumptions you can 'jury rig' $U$ so that this does not hold.

Comment: What do you mean by 'jury rig'? Could you point out what part was wrong in my edited thought? Thanks.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you assumed: (1) $U$ is convex; (2) $S_{\zeta}$ is compact and (3) $\tilde{\zeta} \in U$. $(2)$ is actually implied by the coercive property. I didn't see you use $(1)$. Thank you.

Comment: I noticed a recent change in the assumptions regarding $U$, I need some time to digest this. I'm not sure what $\|x\| \to \partial U$ means.

Comment: Sorry I changed $U$ to be bounded which I thought should not matter too much. In checking my real situation, I noticed my $U$ is possibly simply connected (if this helps in any way.) Thanks.

Comment: @copper.hat: I just noticed $\|x\| \to \partial U$ was a typo. I mean $x \to \partial U$ in the sense: for every sequence $\{x_k\} \subset U$ such that $x_k \to y$ where $y \in \partial U$.

Comment: I think with the updated assumption that $\tilde{\zeta} \in S_\zeta$ without further assumptions. Some minor details need to be addressed, but otherwise the proof below is valid without the convexity assumption or the necessity to assume that $S_\zeta$ is compact.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks. Could you point out what property is more crucial here? The coercive property? Or the boundedness of $U$?

Comment: Both are needed to conclude that the level sets are compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that $U$ is convex and that $S_\zeta $ is compact (so $c$
is finite).

If $\tilde{\zeta}=\zeta$, then we have $\tilde{\zeta}\in S_\zeta$, so we can
assume that $\tilde{\zeta}\ne \zeta$.

I am also assuming that $\tilde \zeta \in U$.

Let $\gamma(t) = g(\zeta + t (\tilde{\zeta}-\zeta))$ and similarly $\phi(t) = f(\zeta + t (\tilde{\zeta}-\zeta))$. We have $\phi'(0) < 0$ and $\phi(0) = \gamma(0) = f(\zeta)$.
Note that $\gamma$ is strictly decreasing (since $g$ is a convex quadratic and $\tilde \zeta$ is the minimiser).

Let $\Sigma = \{ t \in [0,1] | \phi(t) \le \phi(0) \}$. 
Note that if $[0,t] \subset \Sigma$ we have $\phi(t) \le \gamma(t)$.

Let $t^* = \sup \{ t | [0,t] \subset \Sigma \}$.
Since $\phi'(0) <0$, we note that $\Sigma$ contains a set
of the form $[0,\delta)$ for some $\delta >0$ and so $t^* >0$.
Suppose $t^* <1$, then by continuity we have $\phi(t^*) \le \gamma(t^*) < \gamma(0) = \phi(0)$ and so there is some open interval $I \subset \Sigma$ containing $t^*$ which
contradicts the maximality of $t^*$. Hence $t^* = 1$.